# mongoose query by nested document properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my mongoose schema is like this.

```
var ProfileAddressSchema = new Schema({
    streetAddress: { type: String, required: true },
    businessAddress: { type: String, required: false },
    country: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Country', required: false },
    city: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City', required: false },
    province: { type: String, required: false },
    postalCode: { type: String, required: false },
    isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    sequence: { type: Number,  default: 0 },
    isDefault: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

var ProfileInfoSchema = new Schema({

    name: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: { type: String, required: false },
    addressList:[ProfileAddressSchema],

});
```

I have tried as follows and that does not works. I want to get the profiles that match with the provided postal code.

```
var criteria = {};
criteria.addressList = {}
criteria.addressList.postalCode = new RegExp(searchPrameters.postalCode, "i"); }
serviceHelper.queryModel(ProfileInfo,criteria, { __v: false },  callback);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to query embedded documents. Your query as a result should be like

```
ProfileInfo.find({
    "addressList.postalCode": new RegExp(searchPrameters.postalCode, "i")
}).exec(callback);
```

So you can construct the query object that has the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) key using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
var criteria = {};
criteria["addressList.postalCode"] = new RegExp(searchPrameters.postalCode, "i"); 
serviceHelper.queryModel(ProfileInfo,criteria, { __v: false },  callback);
```

For more examples, refer to the manual on the section [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).